# Convert 20191107 to Y-m-d date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Please help me converts 20191107 to %Y-%m-%d date in pandas

Input: 20191107

Expected output: 2019-11-07

Comment: please explore `strptime` and `strftime` in python:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: I am not able to get the solution. Can u help?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('20191107', format='%Y%m%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` ?

Comment: @tanvi in pure python you can try:

`import datetime
str=20191107
datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.strptime(str,"%Y%M%d"),"%Y-%M-%d")`

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. My code ran finally :)